# How to ensure a CPropertyPage has been created BEFORE user clicks on it in a CPropertySheet?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have created a `CPropertySheet`-based modal dialog in MFC (using BCGSoft classes derived from `CPropertySheet` / `CPropertyPage`).  When a user takes a certain action in one of the `CPropertyPage`'s, I would like to enable/disable a control in a different `CPropertyPage`.

This works just fine, assuming the user has already clicked on the tab to instantiate the second `CPropertyPage`.  However, MFC delays the creation of the second `CPropertyPage` until it is activated by the user.  In this scenario, the control within the second `CPropertyPage` does not exist, and MFC throws an error.

To overcome this, I would like to ensure that all `CPropertyPage`'s exist by calling the necessary functions within the `CPropertySheet` `OnInitDialog()`.  Can someone please explain how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the function `CPropertyPage::SetActivePage()` (on an actual `CPropertyPage` object, of course) does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your data is not separate from the UI (a bad thing). It is best to redesign your business logic to separate your data from the UI, so you can populate initial data even without UI.

If you have to, in OnInitDialog, [set the active page to each page in a loop](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2090/Hacking-the-CPropertySheet), then activate the default page.

Comment: In my case, it is purely a user-interface convenience to cause a checkbox to be checked in another page, rather than a business logic requirement.  No data is being changed, or set.  I could add a new property in the data layer (a data layer already exists, and is read when the second page loads/saves) and read this data when the second page becomes active, but I'd rather not add unnecessary data into the data layer.  In this scenario, I just want the checkbox in the second page to become checked.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to enable the controls immediately, do it in the OnActivate method for the page.